# Converting List to Dictionary with key from different lists

Tags: c#, .net, list, dictionary

I have several lists of several different classes (R, L , S):

```
List<R> someListR = ...;
List<L> someListL = ...;
List<S> someListS = ...;
```

Each class has an integer `Id` field but they all have unique Ids.

I want to convert `someList3` to a `Dictionary<string, S>` with the key being:

```
R.Id + ":" + L.Id
```

**EDIT:**

The Lists sizes can be different and in that case I would create a key.

For example a List R has:

```
R1.Id = 111;
R2.Id = 222;
R3.Id = 333;
```

and List L:

```
L1.Id = 123;
L2.Id = 234;
L3.Id = 345;
L4.Id = 456;
```

I want to create a key=> value dictionary like this:

```
111:123 => S1
222:234 => S2
333:345 => S3
```

Comment: Read the golden rule https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: The question is not clear. Are the `Id` in all three classes the same? Show simplifies sample input and expected output.

Comment: No the Ids in all three classes are different.

Comment: Does each list have the same count of items? If L has less items than R, should a Key be derived?

Comment: @stackErr so you want to throw away `Id's` of `S` and replace each of them with `R.Id + ":" + L.Id` ? are the sizes of lists are the same?

Comment: edited question. Hopefully I provided enough information now.

Comment: @stackErr please clarify you want the dictionary with key as "111:123" and value as what ?

Comment: @Thanigainathan The value is the class `S`.

Comment: @stackErr so you have two lists R and L. You are joining them with the unique ids and filling the class s collection with properties. Please tell me if I am correct ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm still not sure I get your question, but looks like you need `Zip` method:

```
var result = listL.Zip(listR, (l,r) => new { l, r })
                  .Zip(listS, (x, s) => new { x.l, x.r, x.s })
                  .ToDictionary(x => x.l.ID + ":" + x.r.ID, x => x.s);
```